# Delete rows with redundant information in r (not just duplicates)

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

In this sample data:

```
id<-c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
time<-c(3,5,7,8,9,2,8,10,12,14,18,4,6,7,9)
status<-c('mar','mar','div','c','mar','mar','div','mar','mar','c','div','mar','mar','c','mar')

myd<-data.frame(id,time,status)

   id time status
1   2    3    mar
2   2    5    mar
3   2    7    div
4   2    8      c
5   2    9    mar
6   3    2    mar
7   3    8    div
8   3   10    mar
9   3   12    mar
10  3   14      c
11  3   18    div
12  4    4    mar
13  4    6    mar
14  4    7      c
15  4    9    mar
```

I need to know when the person married (if there are two consecutive 'mar' rows without 'div' anywhere in between, the person never divorced, hence it's the same marriage, and we don't need the timing of that repeat information; the same goes with sequence of mar, c, mar where since div is not detected, the marriage before and after child are the same marriage, hence the second one can be deleted). I suspect I need to get min(time[status=='mar']) but this would be incorrect if that person gets a mar,mar,div,mar,div,mar sequence (only 2nd mar needs deletion, not all the ones after the first one).

So the new data should look something like

```
   id time status
2   2    5    mar
3   2    7    div
4   2    8      c
5   2    9    mar
6   3    2    mar
7   3    8    div
8   3   10    mar
10  3   14      c
11  3   18    div
13  4    6    mar
14  4    7      c
```

This was my approach, which only worked for one row

```
myd2<-myd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(dum1=ifelse(status=='mar',min(time[status=='mar']),NA),
         dum2=cumsum(status=='div'),
         flag=ifelse(time>dum1 & dum2==0,1,0))
```

If I get rid of dum2==0 then it deleted too many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a quick helper function,

```r
func <- function(x, vals = c("mar", "div")) {
  out <- rep(TRUE, length(x))
  last <- x[1]
  for (ind in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
    out[ind] <- x[ind] != last || !x[ind] %in% vals
    if (out[ind] && x[ind] %in% vals) last <- x[ind]
  }
  out
}
```

We can do

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(myd)[, .SD[func(status),], by = .(id)]
#        id  time status
#     <num> <num> <char>
#  1:     2     3    mar
#  2:     2     7    div
#  3:     2     8      c
#  4:     2     9    mar
#  5:     3     2    mar
#  6:     3     8    div
#  7:     3    10    mar
#  8:     3    14      c
#  9:     3    18    div
# 10:     4     4    mar
# 11:     4     7      c
```

If you want this in `dplyr`, then

```r
library(dplyr)
myd %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(func(status))
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I find having to write a for loop the hardest part of coding, but I guess maybe for this problem there is no way around it.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the often-preferred method of vectorized-calcs and such have a liability: memory-less computation: the calculation of one is regardless of the results of the previous calculation. `for` loops are not bad, and sometimes they really are the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

```
library(dplyr)

myd %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>%
  filter(status != lag(status) | is.na(lag(status))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id  time status
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     2     3 mar
 2     2     7 div
 3     2     8 c
 4     2     9 mar
 5     3     2 mar
 6     3     8 div
 7     3    10 mar
 8     3    14 c
 9     3    18 div
10     4     4 mar
11     4     7 c
12     4     9 mar
```

Comment: I understand deleting the duplicates when they are consecutive, but in the case of ID 4, this person was married, had a child, and documented as married again (no divorce in between), so the  marriage after 'c' is still the same marriage as before 'c', so should be deleted. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I would delete rows in which the status is unchanged by creating a `lag_status` variable in grouped data:

```
> myd %>% 
+     arrange(id, time) %>% 
+     group_by(id) %>% 
+     mutate(lag_status = lag(status)) %>%
+     ungroup() %>% 
+     filter(is.na(lag_status) | status != lag_status) %>% 
+     select(-lag_status)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id  time status
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> 
 1     2     3 mar   
 2     2     7 div   
 3     2     8 c     
 4     2     9 mar   
 5     3     2 mar   
 6     3     8 div   
 7     3    10 mar   
 8     3    14 c     
 9     3    18 div   
10     4     4 mar   
11     4     7 c     
12     4     9 mar
```

Comment: This works if the sequence of 'mar' are consecutive, but not when there's a 'c' in between (in the case of id number 4).  Sorry my question was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I read two different questions in your post.

1. When the person first married
2. How to make a list that removes redundant status information

It seems like you have a solution for #1, but you actually want #2.

I read #2 as a desire to filter out rows where the id and status are the same as the previous row. That would look like:

```
myd %>%
  filter(!(id == lag(id) & status == lag(status))
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my question (now edited), any 'mar' row is redundant when 'div' doesn't happen in between, so when there's a sequence like 'mar','c','mar', 'c' (married, child, married, child), since there's no 'div' detected they're assumed to be the same 'mar', so the second 'mar' is redundant in this case as well.